# How to build a laravel + react + inertia + breeze first application?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm following this tutorial to create laravel + react + inertia + breeze first application

```
https://larainfo.com/blogs/laravel-inertia-js-crud-with-react-tutorial
```

and type the following commands

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel inertia-react
    cd inertia-react
    composer require laravel/breeze --dev
    php artisan breeze:install
    php artisan breeze:install react
    npm install && npm run dev
```

and then it just show the error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react\resources\js\app.js' 
in 'D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react'
```

Do anyone know how to fix it?

full bug log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\xampp74\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\CWindow10\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;;D:\Program Files (x86)\easyshare\x86\;D:\Program Files (x86)\easyshare\x64\;D:\CWindow10\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;D:\CWindow10\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\CWindow10\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Roaming\npm;
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

file 2

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'development'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\xampp74\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\CWindow10\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;;D:\Program Files (x86)\easyshare\x86\;D:\Program Files (x86)\easyshare\x64\;D:\CWindow10\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;D:\CWindow10\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\CWindow10\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hkveg\AppData\Roaming\npm;
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'mix' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~development: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: @ development: `mix`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd D:\xampp74\htdocs\lara3\inertia-react
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "development"
18 verbose node v14.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ development: `mix`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I build a Laravel + React + Inertia + Breeze first application:

1- Install Laravel:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
cd example-app
```

2- Install Breeze starter kit for React (includes Inertia):

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install react
```

3- Run the project (dev mode):

In 1st terminal (Laravel): `php artisan serve`

And in 2nd one (Vite): `npm run dev`

Docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia

Comment: i have the same error , why?

Comment: Can you try it outside XAMPP? If so, let me know.

Comment: i'm trying to use linux to do that, but i can't access the app, see the latest images

Comment: try to run it like this `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`. If works, I'll update my answer and explain why --host 0.0.0.0 does the trick

Comment: it is still the same, i had tried to access inside the virtualbox by using firefox inside, it redirects me to https://192.168.1.113, not http://, i also tried to access http://192.168.1.113/ from my window host, but it still unable to connect

Comment: http://192.168.1.113:5173/ i can see a page like welcome from my window host, but i can't access app_url

Comment: At this point, I don't know how to help. Have you tried http://127.0.0.1:8000 to access the app?

Comment: i saw the webpage http://127.0.0.1:8000, and i can access login & register, but even i  turn the "npm run dev" off, i can still access the page, what "npm run dev" for? I'm wondering is  http://127.0.0.1:8000 already a react pwa website, it looks like a simple laravel website but not a pwa?

Comment: wdym by turn the `npm run dev` off? `127.0.0.1:8000` is the ip from where you are serving the laravel application and the port is the default port that `php artisan serve` uses to serve your laravel application. vite is another program that runs in parallel and takes care of the frontend. What a PWA has to do with this (just asking)?

Comment: because i don't understand why vite console is turned off (ctrl + c), the website is still running. So what is the usage of 'npm run dev"?
I want to learn develop a pwa with Laravel backend + and react fronted. I need to make sure i'm going to right direction

Comment: to decide if the app is running or not, u just run `php artisan serve` or not. as i said, vite is used to build the frontend, but once is built, u can just stop vite, it's already built. the thing is that if u make a new change in the frontend, as you have stopped vite, you won't see that change, but yet the previous changes u did before. so normally vite is running while u are developing (u dont stop it), so u see the changes instantly and don't have to compile the frontend manually. and yeah,you are going the right direction.